# VBA Class Module - When to Stop and Where to declare public constant?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been coding vba for quite sometime now and it is only recently that I have begun diving into doing up some class module.

some questions on my mind is when should I stop including functions and properties in a class ?

i.e. I am creating a class module where by it record table properties (i.e. row of header column) I went on further to create a retrieve data function where it gets data from other table with the same class.

Question 1: am I over doing it?  I tend to want to put all the function in one class.

Question 2: if I want to set all classes to have the same default initialization do I declare a public const in the class module itself or the normal modules?

Here is my class module :

```
    Private pHeaderNames As Object
    Private pHeaderRow As Long

    Private pSubHeaderNames As Object
    Private pSubHeaderRow As Long

    Private pDataRowStart As Long
    Private pInputColStart As Long
    Private pTableColStart As Long
    Private pHeaderLastCol As Long

    Private pTblWorksheet As Worksheet
    Private pFileURL As String
    Private pFileName As String



    '---------------------------------------------- Initialization
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        pHeaderRow = 1
        pDataRowStart = 2
        pTableColStart = 1
        pInputColStart = pTableColStart
        pSubHeaderRow = pHeaderRow
        pHeaderLastCol = Cells(pHeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set pHeaderNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set pSubHeaderNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub


    Public Property Get FileURL() As String
        FileURL = pFileURL
    End Property

    Public Property Let FileURL(Value As String)
        pFileURL = Value
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileName() As String
        FileName = pFileName
    End Property

    Public Property Let FileName(Value As String)
        pFileName = Value
    End Property


    Function OpenWorkbook(URL As String, Name As String)
        pFileURL = URL
        pFileName = Name
        Call Workbook_open(pFileURL, pFileName)
    End Function


    Public Property Let SetSheet(Value As String)
        If pFileName - "" Then
            Set pTblWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Value)
        Else
            Set pTblWorksheet = Workbook(pFileName).Worksheets(Value)
        End If
    End Property









    Public Property Get TblWorksheet() As Worksheet
        TblWorksheet = pTblWorksheet
    End Property

    Public Property Let TblWorksheet(Sheet As Worksheet)
        pTblWorksheet = Sheet
    End Property












    '---------------------------------------------- HeaderLastCol
    Public Property Get HeaderLastCol() As Long
        HeaderLastCol = pHeaderLastCol
    End Property

    Public Property Let HeaderLastCol(Value As Long)
        pHeaderLastCol = Value
    End Property


    '---------------------------------------------- HeaderRow
    Public Property Let HeaderRow(Value As Long)
        pHeaderLastCol = Cells(pHeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        pHeaderRow = Value
    End Property

    Public Property Get HeaderRow() As Long
        HeaderRow = pHeaderRow
    End Property


    '---------------------------------------------- SubHeaderRow
    Public Property Let SubHeaderRow(Value As Long)
        pSubHeaderRow = Value
    End Property

    Public Property Get SubHeaderRow() As Long
        SubHeaderRow = pSubHeaderRow
    End Property


    '---------------------------------------------- InputColStart
    Sub SetInputColStart(KEY As Variant)
        pInputColStart = pHeaderNames(KEY)
    End Sub

    Public Property Get InputColStart() As Long
        InputColStart = pInputColStart
    End Property

    Public Property Let InputColStart(Value As Long)
        pInputColStart = Value
    End Property


    '---------------------------------------------- DataRowStart
    Public Property Get DataRowStart() As Long
        DataRowStart = pDataRowStart
    End Property

    Public Property Let DataRowStart(Value As Long)
        pDataRowStart = Value
    End Property



    '---------------------------------------------- TableColStart
    Public Property Get TableColStart() As Long
        TableColStart = pTableColStart
    End Property


    Public Property Let TableColStart(Value As Long)
        pTableColStart = Value
    End Property


    '---------------------------------------------- HeaderName
    Sub GetHeaderNames()
        With pHeaderNames
            For i = pTableColStart To pHeaderLastCol
                If Not .Exists(UCase(Cells(pHeaderRow, i).Value)) Then
                          .Add UCase(Cells(pHeaderRow, i).Value), i
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End Sub

    Function HeaderName(KEY As String)
        If pHeaderNames.Exists(KEY) Then
            HeaderName = pHeaderNames(KEY)
        Else
            HeaderName = ""
        End If
    End Function

    Function CountHeaderNames()
        CountHeaderNames = pHeaderNames.Count
    End Function

    Function PrintHeaderObject()
        For Each KEY In pHeaderNames.keys
            Debug.Print KEY, pHeaderNames(KEY)
        Next
    End Function


    '---------------------------------------------- SubHeaderName
    Sub GetSubHeaderNames()
        With pSubHeaderNames
            For i = pTableColStart To pHeaderLastCol
                If Not .Exists(UCase(Cells(pSubHeaderRow, i).Value)) Then
                          .Add UCase(Cells(pSubHeaderRow, i).Value), i
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End Sub

    Function SubHeaderName(KEY As String)
        If pSubHeaderNames.Exists(KEY) Then
            SubHeaderName = pSubHeaderNames(KEY)
        Else
            SubHeaderName = "" 'or raise an error...
        End If
    End Function

    Function CountSubHeaderNames()
        CountSubHeaderNames = pSubHeaderNames.Count
    End Function

    Function PrintSubHeaderObject()
        For Each KEY In pSubHeaderNames.keys
            Debug.Print KEY, pSubHeaderNames(KEY)
        Next
    End Function



    Function RetrieveData(FromSht As Worksheet, ByVal FromTable As cTable)

        Dim KEY As String


        'CurrentSht = ActiveSheet
        For i = pTableColStart To pHeaderLastCol
            KEY = Cells(pHeaderRow, i).Value
            If FromTable.HeaderName(KEY) = "" Then
                GoTo Nexti
            Else
                With FromSht
                    .Activate
                    rD_LastRow = 10
                    Set Source = .Range(.Cells(FromTable.DataRowStart, FromTable.HeaderName(KEY)), _
                                        .Cells(rD_LastRow, FromTable.HeaderName(KEY)))
                End With

                With CurrentSht
                    .Activate
                    .Range(.Cells(DataRowStart, i), _
                            .Cells(DataRowStart, i)) _
                            .Resize(Source.Rows.Count, Source.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = Source.Cells.Value
                End With
            End If



Nexti:
        Next i


    End Function
```

Here is the module, so you can see that I have always need to declare headerRow , subHeaderRow and Datarowstart, even thou I have a default initialization set in the class module, is there away to change the default initialization based on the main module? or I just have to do it in the class module?  (I trying to make the class portable)

```
Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht = wb.Sheets("Skin(Units)")


With Worksheets("Skin(Units)")
    .Activate
    Set SkinUnits = New cTable

    Debug.Print TypeName(SkinUnits)
    SkinUnits.HeaderRow = 1
    SkinUnits.SubHeaderRow = 3
    SkinUnits.DataRowStart = 4
    SkinUnits.GetHeaderNames
    SkinUnits.GetSubHeaderNames

    SkinUnits.PrintHeaderObject
    SkinUnits.PrintSubHeaderObject
    SkinUnits.SetInputColStart ("Start")
End With


With Worksheets("Pain(Units)")
    .Activate
    Set PainUnits = New cTable

    PainUnits.HeaderRow = 1
    PainUnits.SubHeaderRow = 3
    PainUnits.DataRowStart = 4
    PainUnits.GetHeaderNames
    PainUnits.GetSubHeaderNames

    PainUnits.PrintHeaderObject
    PainUnits.PrintSubHeaderObject
    PainUnits.SetInputColStart ("Start")
    Debug.Print PainUnits.HeaderName("SKU")
    Debug.Print TypeName(sht), TypeName(SkinUnits)
    Call test22222(SkinUnits)
    Call PainUnits.RetrieveData(sht, SkinUnits)

End With



End Sub


Function test22222(ByVal X As cTable)


    Debug.Print X.HeaderRow


End Function
```

Comment: If this code works as intended, this would be a great question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Just make sure to go through the asking guidelines there, they're a little different.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will direct this question to code review :)

Comment: @Ryeo  Q's like yours asking for a review of code are _not_ off topic on SO (provided they meet other criteria) Please don't feel that you must move it to Code-Review. But if you do, please ensure you meet their Q requirements.

Comment: Question 1: Class is your custom object. You give it all the properties and methods you want it to have. If you feel like you may have too many look for duplication, or decide if all methods are actually required. Otherwise implement what you need I would have thought. Also, be aware you can implement [interfaces and inheritance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RetQsyKkHlo).